# Biometrics for TRV Canada, VFS says no appointments left, do I need one?

Tags: visas, canada, nigerian-citizens

So I submitted my visa application for TRV,  and I got an e-mail today that I should submit my biometrics for my application and I have 30 days left, I go through the VAC online and they say there are no appointment days left.

I have something I want to ask, is it mandatory? Do I have to schedule an appointment or I can walk in with my passport and Biometric Request letter form without one?

I am from Nigeria.

Comment: If the system requires you to book an appointment it’s unlikely they’d process your biometrics without one. Perhaps if you check the system daily there’ll be availability eg due to a cancellation. If you live close to the VAC I guess you could try turning up there

Comment: @Traveller does not say i must book appointments. I guess , going to the VAC in person should do.

Answer (score 3):

You are definitely NOT required to book an appointment, it is only suggested. [Source](https://www.vfsglobal.ca/canada/nigeria/biometrics.html):

> Scheduling an appointment for Biometric Enrolment is optional – walk-in clients are always welcome to submit their biometrics without a prior appointment. Note however that a planned visit with a preferred time slot via an appointment at the Visa Application Centre guarantees prompt service, thus eliminating longer waiting time resulting in inconvenience. You can schedule an appointment at the nearest Visa Application Centre, either through the VAC website or by calling the call center at +2348150199900.